# Разрешения экранов в Android

Tags: android

Есть изображение для фона приложения. Подскажите каких размеров обычно делают такие изображения для экранов

mdpi
hdpi
xhdpi
xxhdpi
xxxhdpi

Чтобы она нормально смотрелась (не искажлась) на всех экранах?

P.S. есть папки для разметок layout, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp

Comment: 800х1200, 1200х1920 и 1600х2560 нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Ни то ни другое, ни первое, ни второе и даже не третье...

Делается так:

1. Дизайнер в полете фантазии рисует *нечто*. Обычно он это рисует в фотошопе (PSD) изредка в Coreldraw (CDR). Обычно исходник или векторный или с разрешением что-то навроде 2к/4к
2. Далее прогер берет исходник и генерирует из него PNG с разрешением не хуже 1к, назовем его оригиналом.
3. Далее из оригинала генерируется то что будет лежать непосредственно в самом приложении. Если речь идет о примитивных иконках то лучше воспользоваться [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

В случае, если речь идет не об иконках, то здесь подойдет [Android Vector Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html), который умеет напрямую работать с PSD и SVG векторными файлами и на выходе генерирует `VectorDrawable`, который умеет растягиваться на любые разрешения.

Comment: Дизайнера у меня нет и полет фантазий ограничен моей фантазией). У меня было векторное изображение, которое я использовал в приложении, но в силу того что версии андроид ниже 5-ой не поддерживают векторные изображения пришлось использовать растровое. Так вот из этого векторного изображения, я получил растровое (оригинал скажем) для экранов mdpi с разрешением примерно 800х1300.. Так вот исходя из этого хотел уточнить для экранов  hdpi и xhdpi как его увеличивать? Также как и другие изображения 1.5 и 2 раза?